# In HP-UX server, grep -r option is not working

Tags: grep, hp-ux

In unix server `grep -r` option is not working. OS is HP-UX.

If `grep -r` is not working any alternative way to do recursive search without `-r` option?

Comment: try ``man grep`` or ``grep --help``

Comment: ya I checked man grep. -r option is not mentioned even in man pages.

Comment: some variant on `find . -type f | xargs grep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `grep -r` is a GNU extension (now supported by a few other implementations, but not standard). Use `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep pattern /dev/null {} +
```

The `/dev/null` is to make sure that `grep` always prints the file name when it finds a match.

Comment: IMHO for find you can use -print to make sure you will get the filename

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I meant to make sure `grep` always prints the filename against the matched line. You don't want the names of all the files to be printed.

Comment: Why not use grep - H ?

Comment: @Archemar, `-H` is another GNU extension.